# CodeIgniter default controller ignored?

Tags: routes, codeigniter-2

In my routes.php I have my `$routes['default_controller'] = "MainController"`, but this doesn't seem to work unless I navigate to /MainController in the browser. What am I missing? Is there something other than this that should be set?

Comment: Please note that *The reserved routes (e.g. `default_controller`) must come before any wildcard or regular expression routes.*

Comment: Through some trial and error I have figured out that the problem is capitalization. If I use maincontroller (as opposed to MainController), I have no problem. CodeIgniter is becoming more and more useless to me.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$routes['default_controller'] = "maincontroller";
```